# Qt properties, underlying data members, bindings and overhead

Tags: c++, qt, binding, properties, qml

I am trying to wrap my head around this. I have a `QObject` derived class being used in QML, it has a `int length` member and a corresponding `length` property.

90% of the times in QML I'd set the property via a binding: `length: 50` or `length: someJSExpression`, and in both cases the value is being determined by an expression, be that a trivial in the case of `50`.

But what does this mean? That the underling `int` remains unused and instead of reading the value from it, it is being evaluated from the bound expression, or that the expression is evaluated and the value is stored into the member, and then read from it?

In the first case the member would simply take up space without being used producing memory consumption overhead, in the second case the overhead will come from the redundant write/read instead of directly using the value from the expression without caching it in the member.

On a deeper level, the question would extend to how bindings, which are purely QML thing and not used in the C+++ API work, whether they substitute the underlying property member or work in tandem with it and the defined (or implicit) getter method.

Also, is there a room for eliminating the overhead in the fist case? I mean it is possible to implement a read-only property that doesn't use any underlying member and the getter method evaluates an expression to determine it, but in those cases in QML it won't be possible to use the other form, i.e. `length = 50` that imply sets the value rather than binding an expression to it?

Comment: I don't get what the question is about. If you have a property on a QObject subclass exposed to QML, and in QML you do `MyThing { myProp: 50 }`, that will create the corresponding object and set the value of the property "myProp" to 50. Where that property gets stored is up to you (member? member of a sub-object? global repository database? cloud?).

Comment: I am equally puzzled by the question in your comment. Let me put it this way, when `length` is bound to an expression, does the reading of the property invoke the bound expression or is the expression already evaluated and stored in the `m_length` member and read from there?

Comment: The latter. The expression gets evaluated and stored into the property (via the WRITE function you specify when declaring the property). Reading the property back happens through the READ function.

Answer (score 0):

QObject properties are linked to QML as they are defined in the QObject using the Q_PROPERTY macro. You have a getter (READ), a setter (WRITE) and a change indicator (NOTIFY).

When QML code needs to set your property, the setter is invoked. When QML reads the value, the getter is invoked.

Your setter should emit the NOTIFY signal, if the value really changes, so that dependent QML expressions can be re-evaluated.

How you store the value of your property is completely up to your C++ code.

Initializing a QML property using `length: 50`, your C++ property will be initialized using your setter and that's all there is to it. If you bind your property with something like `length: parent.length + 3` your C++ property will also get initialized using your setter, but QML will install a listener, which listens to source values (`parent.length` in the last example) and will re-evaluate the expression, whenever a source value changes. Thus, if anyone changes `parent.length`, your setter will get called with the new evaluation of `parent.length + 3`.

This makes bound properties very cheap to use, as long as they are read more often than they are written. Also, making a lot of properties depend on a single property will increase the cost for changing the value of that property.

Yes, you can have read-only properties without a setter or underlying data. You only need something, which you can calculate. Note, that whatever you calculate there should not change until you have emitted the NOTIFY signal. Otherwise, QML values, which are bound to your property will not be able to be updated.